# Excel Formula: Count repetition factor in a list (Vlookup/Indirect help)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Apologies for the confusing title; I will explain my issue more clearly and detailed here.

So I have a list of booleans that includes a repetitive pattern, and I am trying to calculate the factor by which it repeats. The list will always begin with an unknown number of FALSE values before it begins the cycle and will always end with a TRUE followed by an unknown, but large number of FALSE values.

An example list:

1. FALSE
2. FALSE
3. TRUE
4. FALSE
5. FALSE
6. FALSE
7. TRUE
8. FALSE
9. FALSE
10. FALSE
11. TRUE
12. FALSE
13. FALSE
14. FALSE
15. FALSE
16. FALSE
17. FALSE

In this case, the factor of repetition I would like is 4 since the pattern repeats every 4 rows (excluding the beginning and end of the list).

I have tried a couple of methods of writing formulas to come up with 4 as the answer including uses of counts, some simple vlookups, and an offset attempt. So far, I have been unable to get a working formula. My guess is that the Indirect function may be of use here, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around the logic of using it yet.

In terms of a general strategy, I'm guessing that if I can find the indices of the rows of the first and second TRUE values, I can simply subtract them to find the repetition factor. (I can easily implement a row number or cell reference column into my spreadsheet if that would help at all too.)

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$17)/($A$1:$A$17),2)-MATCH(TRUE,$A$1:$A$17,0)
```

The MATCH finds the first row in which there is a TRUE.

The AGGREGATE is working like the SMALL(IF()) Function.  when the cell is FALSE it will return a division by 0 error and the 6 in the function overlooks the errors.  So the array in which the AGGREGATE is going to pull the second lowest row number is on those rows in which the cell is TRUE.

[image]

---

Edit

Here is a non array formula that does it also, based loosely on @GaryStudents answer:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,A:A,0)+1):A1040000,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly! Would you mind stepping through the logic of this function briefly? I have never used the aggregate function before and the OfficeSupport guides are somewhat confusing to follow in this case. @Scott Craner

Comment: Good answer!  My answer uses *INDIRECT()* which I dislike.

Comment: Perfect! I saw that you were using the SMALL function and ignoring errors, but didn't realize exactly what it was looking for with the division in the middle. Thanks again! @Scott Craner

Comment: @Gary'sStudent see edit I added a non array formula based loosely on yours.

Comment: @SpippyTheInsane I added another formula that is not an array type.  I would use the second one instead.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Is there a particular reason you dislike using the Indirect function? Is it bad practice?

Comment: @SpippyTheInsane it is a volatile function, it will recalculate every time excel recalculates even if the data to which it references has changed or not.  Non volatile functions do not recalculate unless the underlying data has changed.  If you have a spread sheet full of INDIRECT, OFFSET and others, it will recalculate all of them every time you change a cell that forces any formula to recalculate.  A lot of wasted cpu time.

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow, I had never even heard of volatile functions before. I really appreciate the insight. In this particular workbook, my data sets are relatively small,  but I am starting a lot of work on SQL databases with hundreds of thousands of rows and dozens of columns, so I will dfeinitely keep this in mind in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Get the "distance" between two consecutive occurrences of *TRUE*:

In **C1** enter:

```
=MATCH("TRUE",A:A,0)
```

and in **C2**:

```
=MATCH("TRUE",INDIRECT("A" & C1+1 & ":A9999"),0)+C1
```

finally in **C3**:

```
=C2-C1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was very similar to what I was attempting to do, but I was unable to write the Indirect syntax correctly for the range and forgot to add the C1 value back in again at the end. Very straightforward, thanks! @Gary's Student

Comment: @SpippyTheInsane there are advantages to this method over mine, in that mine is an array type formula and the references should only be the data set.  While this method uses helper cells to avoid the array type.  The only thing I would do different is avoid the volatile INDIRECT with INDEX but with a one off it should not make a difference in speed.  The advantage to mine is it is all in one formula.

Comment: @SpippyTheInsane  You are quite welcome.  Use Scott's formula unless your version of Excel does not support *Aggregate()*